# pytest | parameterize two dictionaries with identicle keys to assert value comparison

Tags: python, dictionary, pytest

I'm  new to pytest, I'm using python 10.

I want to parameterize two dictionaries that have the same keys with different values but I want to check if the values of a key in one dictionary is x10 bigger than the value of the same key in the other dictionary. I want parameterization, because I want the pytest output to PASS or FAIL depending on the key.

so

```
dict1 = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3}
dict2 = {"a": 10, "c": 30, "b": 20}
```

and the test would be like:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("dict1_dict", dict1)
@pytest.mark.parametrize("dict2_dict", dict2)    
def test_by_ten(dict1_dict, dict2_dict):
   assert dict1_dict[key] == dict2_dict[key] * 10
```

I don't know if that's possible and how to pull the same key from both dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your tests with the `--collect-only` flag, you will be able to see that what you are actually doing is generating a test case for all the possible combinations of the dictionary keys. Also notice that what you would get in the test when you parametrize it with a dictionary, is the key of the dictionary, not the dictionary itself, so `dict1_dict[key]` wouldn't be a valid operation.

```
<Module test_example.py>
  <Function test_by_ten[a-a]>
  <Function test_by_ten[a-b]>
  <Function test_by_ten[a-c]>
  <Function test_by_ten[c-a]>
  <Function test_by_ten[c-b]>
  <Function test_by_ten[c-c]>
  <Function test_by_ten[b-a]>
  <Function test_by_ten[b-b]>
  <Function test_by_ten[b-c]>
```

I assume that what you want is to generate 3 test cases in total, comparing the key in one dictionary with the same key in the other one. There are many different ways to achieve that, one possibility is to use the keys to parametrize the test.

```python
dict1 = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3}
dict2 = {"a": 10, "c": 30, "b": 20}

@pytest.mark.parametrize("dict_keys", dict1.keys())
def test_by_ten(dict_keys):
    assert dict2[dict_keys] == dict1[dict_keys] * 10
```